# Accessing the return values of a complex variable in prolog

Tags: prolog

i am new in prolog and I trying to achieve the following:

I have these 2 rules so far.

```
family(
    person(tom, fox, date(7, may, 1950), works(bbc, 15200)),
    person(ann, fox, date(9, may, 1951), unemployed),
     [person(pat, fox, date(5, may, 1973), unemployed),
    person(jim, fox, date(5, may, 1973), unemployed)]
    ).

child(X):- 
    family(_, _, Children),member(X, Children).
```

When I call the `child(X)` I get:

```
X = person(pat, fox, date(5, may, 1973), unemployed) ;
X = person(jim, fox, date(5, may, 1973), unemployed)
```

and what I seek to do is find whether a child is unemployed. But since X is returning the person() and not a single value, how can I access only the last element of this rule and check if its value is equal to "unemployed"?
So basically I want to create a new rule looking something like this:

```
childworking(X):-
  child(X), (check if the last value of the person() is equal to unemployed).
```

If the value of `child(X)` was returned in a list I could do something like `child(X),member(unemployed,X)` but this is not the case...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
childworking(X) :-
    child(X), X = person(_,_,_,unemployed)
```

Says that X must be a child, and X must be a person of any firstname, any surname, any birthdate and `unemployed` job status.

Answer (score -2):

Another way: the predicate `=..` "univ" can change things between compound and list forms, then you can use list predicates to get the last thing, e.g.

```
?- person(pat, fox, date(5, may, 1973), unemployed) =.. List

List = [person, pat, fox, date(5, may, 1973), unemployed]
```

So:

```
childworking(X) :-
    child(X), X=..Y, last(Y, unemployed).
```